# small-scale field trial?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In Portugal, Germany, France and the Czech Republic,  transgenic crops were primarily grown for **small-scale field trials.**

Whats the meaning of small scale field trial?

Does this sentence means that ***those transgenic crops are given to the cattle as food as well as marketed for the mass consumption to satisfy their needs***

[Source](http://www.gmo-compass.org/eng/agri_biotechnology/gmo_planting/142.countries_growing_gmos.html) [read first paragraph]

Answer (score 1):

A *field trial* (also *field test* or *field experiment*) means a test or experiment performed under conditions which are **more natural** and **less controlled** than in a laboratory experiment.

It does not need to involve a literal field (paddock).  For example, this quote is from an example of a [field trial](http://www.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/4g-lte-field-trials-announced-by-everything-everywhere-and-bt-958912) in telecommunications which involves providing equipment to customers:

> 100 mobile and 100 fixed line customers in the St Newlyn East area of
>   South Newquay, Cornwall will be included in the trial.
>
> Apparently a test at BT's labs in Adastal Park in Surrey is already
>   underway, but the field trial will give a much better measure of the
>   new technology

The definition of a *small-scale* trial is not very clear in many cases.  Here, it probably means "one to a few fields" - not necessarily that the fields themselves were small. A trial on one large field might still be considered a small-scale trial.